# ORACLE: PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to catch the following error **ORA-01442**

[image]

In my script below, does it need the leading zero? -**01442** or -**1442** which of the two values and why?

```
----------------------------------
    -- Alter column null --
    ----------------------------------
    DECLARE
       allready_null EXCEPTION;
       PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(allready_null, -01442);
    BEGIN
       execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE NMSACTIVECONTACT MODIFY ("ISOURCEID" NULL)';
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN allready_null THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('ISOURCEID is already null, skipping...');
    END;
    /
```

It came to my attention when it fail to catch the exeption because the error code was different.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. Error code is a **number**, so leading zero doesn't affect it.

As [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/exceptioninit_pragma.htm) says about error number in `EXCEPTION_INIT` pragma:

> Any valid Oracle error number. These are the same error numbers (always negative) returned by the function `SQLCODE`.